# Counting and Joining Tables

Tags: mysql

I have two tables. One is the "probe" and the other "transcript".

Probe table: "probe"

ProbeID-------TranscriptID----

```
2655       4555555
2600       5454542
2600       4543234
2344       5659595
```

...etc

Transcript table: "transcript"

TranscriptID----Location----

```
7896736      chr1
5454542      chr1
```

...etc

I need to find out how many transcripts per chromosome? AND How many probes per chromosome?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM transcript
```

= '28869' #Above I think gives me the transcripts per chromosome (i.e. location).

I need help with answering the second part (and first, if its wrong). I am assuming I need to use the `JOIN` clause.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Number of probes per chromosone**

```
SELECT Location, COUNT(ProbeID) AS ProbeCnt
FROM transcript T
JOIN probe P ON P.TransciprtID = T.TranscriptID
GROUP BY Location
-- optionally you can ORDER BY to either get
-- ORDER BY COUNT(ProbID) DESC  --  list in descending order of nb of probes
-- ORDER BY Location            --  list in order of chromosome name
```

As to your first query it is incorrect.  To get
**the number of transcripts per chromosome**, you need

```
SELECT Location, COUNT(TranscriptID) as TransCnt
FROM transcript
GROUP BY Location
```

Your current query gives the total number of transcripts for the whole transcript table, regardless of the chromosome.

Answer (score 0):

Transcripts Count

```
select location, count(location) AS transacripts_num 
from transcript GROUP by location;
```

Probe Count

```
select location, count(location) AS probe_num 
from transcript t join probe p
ON t.transcriptId= p.probeId
GROUP by location;
```